# Use cached version of jQuery if recent enough, otherwise download the latest

Tags: jquery

Can I do the following to shave milliseconds of loading for some users?

Fix a suitable version `x` of jQuery, say `x = 1.4.1`, and find the most recent version `y` of jQuery cached by the user. Then,

```
if (y > x === true) {
     /* Use the cached version y of jQuery */
} else {
     /* Download and use the latest version of jQuery */
}
```

Also, would this be *advantageous*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching doesn't work this way.  You won't know whether or not jQuery is cached in the browser, because it won't be present in the DOM until you include a script reference to it.  If that script reference happens to be to a URL that's previously been cached in that browser (your odds of this will improve if you're using a public CDN), then you get the benefits of caching for free.

In short, the only thing you can really do here to optimize "cache hits" is to use a publicly hosted copy of jQuery, [like one of these](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery).

Answer (score 1):

i'd just load jQuery from google cdn because many sites use that so chances are high that it's already cached.

also i wouldn't recommend using the latest jQuery automatically because some changes could break your code

Comment: If a brand new version of jQuery comes out, but I don't new the absolute _latest_ version, then I prefer not to download for nothing.

Comment: I think you're a little confused around how browsers cache JavaScript.  This answer is correct (+1), but also give mine a read since it may help clarify caching a little.

Answer (score 0):

It would took too many resources and would make it even harder.

However you can check current downloaded version with

```
var jQueryVer = null;
if ($){
    var jQueryVer = $().jquery;
}
```

Comment: This will throw an error if jQuery isn't already included in the page.

Comment: @jmar777: sure. I assume jquery is loaded

Comment: But the question concerns conditionally loading jQuery into the page, so that doesn't seem like a safe assumption.